# When updating retention policy getting error - The object has been updated by another user since it was last fetched

Tags: content-type, retention

I'm trying to create retention policies for some of the content types in a document library. The first one is created fine but when I go to create one for the second content type I get the above exception.

The calls to this function are like this:

```
SPList documentLibrary = web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.MyDocumentsLibraryName);

if (documentLibrary == null)
{
    Logger.LogVerbose(LogCategory.Setup,
        "Document Library not found in site " + web.Title);
    return;
}

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

AddRetentionPolicy(Constants.TestContentType, web, documentLibrary, site.Url);
AddRetentionPolicy(Constants.AnotherContentType, web, documentLibrary, site.Url);

documentLibrary.Update();
```

}

And the function itself is:

```
public static void AddRetentionPolicy(String contentTypeName, SPWeb web, 
    SPList documentLibrary, string siteUrl)
{
    Logger.LogVerbose(LogCategory.Setup, "Getting content type " + contentTypeName);
    SPContentType contentType =
        documentLibrary.ContentTypes[contentTypeName];
    if (contentType == null)
    {
        Logger.LogVerbose(LogCategory.Setup, "Cannot find content type " + 
             contentTypeName + ", skipping.");
    }
    else
    {
        Policy policy = Policy.GetPolicy(contentType);
        if (policy != null)
        {
            Logger.LogVerbose(LogCategory.Setup, "Policy already exists for "
                + contentTypeName + ", deleting.");
            Policy.DeletePolicy(contentType);
        }

        Policy.CreatePolicy(contentType, null);

        policy = Policy.GetPolicy(contentType);
        policy.Items.Add("Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.Expiration",
            GeneratePolicyItemXML(Constants.retentionPeriod, Constants.retentionPeriodUnits, 
            web.Title, siteUrl, web.ServerRelativeUrl));

        contentType.Update();
    }
}
```

The error is occurring on the line:

```
Policy.CreatePolicy(contentType, null);
```

Comment: any idea? I'm getting the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Solution: don't pass the list in your method, re-get it each time in the function. Reason: because of the policy that was updated for the content type, your list is also updated so solution is to re-get the list

```
SPList documentLibrary = web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.MyDocumentsLibraryName);
```

before getting the SPContentType